# How to configure base url for all requests using HTMX?

Tags: htmx

Given example from the docs

```
  <button hx-post="/clicked"
       hx-trigger="click"
       hx-target="#parent-div"
       hx-swap="outerHTML">
    Click Me!
  </button>
```

I want to change `<scheme>://<netloc>/clicked` to`<scheme>://<netloc>/api/v1/clicked`, so  prepend `/api/v1` into the base URL so all requests use this version. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is to just alter the event path.

```
            <script>
                document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {
                    event.detail.path = `/api/v1/${event.detail.path}`
                })
            </script>
```

Comment: Looks good, but as its a few years later: did you find a better way? I want to replace the scheme and netloc.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used htmx since then, so I did not.